# Synchronize multiple AVPlayers

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, uiview, avplayer

I am trying to find a solution for a problem I got. I have 5 `UIView`s, which are all at the same position. Each `UIView` holds an `AVPlayer` with different videos. To be more precise they are all the same video, but encoded with different playback speed.

1. Video 1x speed
2. Video 4x speed
3. Video 8x speed
4. Video 16x speed
5. Video 24x speed

By default the video 1 is visible and playing, but I should be able to switch between the videos, but the switching shouldn't be visible for the user, therefore, I need to keep them synchronized. So If I am watching video 1 and switch to video 2, then video 2 should play exactly at the position, where video 1 stopped.

The sense is that it should look like, that the video is speeding up after an action, eg. a flick gesture.

I hope I described my issue good enough and I am very thankful for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using in the end an observer, which takes snapshots  of the `currentTime` each 5 seconds, and calls all the other `AVPLayer` with the `seekToTime` method. This works fine to keep them synchronized. I just needed to adapt the `CMTime` for each player with different speed. As an example I got here 4x video:

```
videoPosition = player1.currentTime;  //gets the video duration
        videoPositionInSeconds = (Float64) videoPosition.value/videoPosition.timescale; //transfers the CMTime duration into seconds
        [player2 seekToTime: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(videoPositionInSeconds/4.0, player1.currentItem.asset.duration.timescale) toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: doesn't it skip slightly when you do this?

Comment: on my device (iPad 3rd gen, Retina) it worked quiet smooth. It wasn't noticeable for users.